# How to display the data in radio button in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, radio-button

Good Day!

How to show the data in radio button in ASP.net the data coming from another sources.

This is the example data which Resident is 1

[image]

I want to display to this 1 means Yes but the result still No.

The number 1 seeing the textbox is getResident.Text

This is the code

```
checkGBP.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var strReturn;  strReturn=window.showModalDialog('gbpCIF.aspx',null,'dialogWidth:1000px;dialogHeight:500px;center:yes;help:no;status: yes;');if (strReturn != null) try{if (strReturn != null) document.getElementById('getResident').value=strReturn.split('|')[1];}catch(err){}")
rdoResidency.SelectedValue = getResident.Text
```

This is the radio button

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "text" of the selected radio button with:

```
 RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text
```

And you can get the "value" of the selected radio button with:

```
 RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value
```

Also in the future - please just post your code, don't post a image. We can't read it well, and can't even cut + paste to try the markup or whatever.